# MapFragment inside frament, when parent activity goes onPause MapFragment becomes null

Tags: android

I have an activity ACTIVITY=>Fragment=>MapFragment

On onPause of ACTIVITY MapFragment becomes null.

Below is method that I am using:

```
 private MapFragment getMapFragment() {
        FragmentManager fm = null;

        Log.d("", "sdk: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
        Log.d("", "release: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            Log.d("framentmgr", "using getFragmentManager");
            fm = getFragmentManager();
        } else {
            Log.d("framentmgr", "using getChildFragmentManager");
            fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        }
//        fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction();

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_map);


        return mapFragment;
    }
```

any solution or reason why this is happening?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks but I was getting same error. So I resolved it now by tricky way, by taking MapFragment as public static in some another class.

```
public static MapFragment mapFragment;
```

and in Fragment class

```
private MapFragment getMapFragment() {
        FragmentManager fm = null;

        Log.d("", "sdk: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
        Log.d("", "release: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            Log.d("framentmgr", "using getFragmentManager");
            fm = getFragmentManager();
        } else {
            Log.d("framentmgr", "using getChildFragmentManager");
            fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        }
//        fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction();

        MapFragment mapFragment = null;
        if(MainActivity.mapFragment==null)
            mapFragment = (MapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_map);
        else
            return MainActivity.mapFragment;


        return mapFragment;
    }
```

Comment: don't keep static references to any UI elements! this way you can easily leak your activity (more - here http://www.curious-creature.com/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/). And please please, do not recommend this to anyone else

Comment: I have tried every possible way, googling, posting on forums. No solution. This is the only solution I got. It is better to leak memory than getting exception and not working state of feature. Please let me know if you have better solution than mine.